Weird behaviour on initialised values of 2d long long arrays caused by initialising an std::string
I was doing advent of code using C++ since I'm a beginner and would like to practise more on it. At one point I kept running my code with the same input but would get a different output each time which is strange. I essentially boiled it down to this reproducible code below:
I put my input in an input file called input.txt
p=0,4 v=3,-3
p=6,3 v=-1,-3
p=10,3 v=-1,2
p=2,0 v=2,-1
p=0,0 v=1,3
p=3,0 v=-2,-2
p=7,6 v=-1,-3
p=3,0 v=-1,-2
p=9,3 v=2,3
p=7,3 v=-1,2
p=2,4 v=2,-3
p=9,5 v=-3,-3

And in my test.cpp file, I have
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string fileLoc = "./" + std::string(argv[1]) + ".txt";
    long long ans[2][2];

    std::cout << ans[0][0] << " " << ans[0][1] << " " << ans[1][0] << " "<< ans[1][1]<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}

for which after build with g++ ./test.cpp -o test and call it with ./test input. Now before you say anything, I'm aware that I have not initialised my long long arrays so the elements could be initialise on a piece of memory that contains gibberish. Now if I were to run my code repeatedly, I see:
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140726245019520 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user@:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140728079005040 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140729072484752 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140727512601312 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140721545315232 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140733041820896 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140723027653216 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140722297215456 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140734807260768 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140732758159440 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140727205009088 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
140736846571504 0 3635659924944006912 1954051118

But if I were to now comment out the line where I initialise std::string from argv, so:
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //std::string fileLoc = "./" + std::string(argv[1]) + ".txt";
    long long ans[2][2];

    std::cout << ans[0][0] << " " << ans[0][1] << " " << ans[1][0] << " "<< ans[1][1]<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}

and run the same code, I see:
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
0 0 0 0
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
0 0 0 0
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
0 0 0 0
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
0 0 0 0
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
0 0 0 0
user:~/develop/cpp/AdventOfCode2024/day14$ ./test input
0 0 0 0

What is going on here? A single initialisation of std::string has caused my uninitialised long long 2d arrays to print gibberish, which you might say it's expected since the elements were not initialised. But how come the behaviour of my second example consistently shows array elements of all 0 despite being not initialised?

Undefined behavior is undefined (reading from an uninitialized array is undefined behavior).

Unless you explicitly initialize variables, including array elements, their values will be indeterminate. And in C++, using indeterminate values in any way (even printing them) leads to undefined behavior. And there's no reason to expect any specific behavior of UB, it is after all undefined.

In the case where the string wasn't initialised, the array elements of the array look pretty determined and defined to me, therefore @Someprogrammerdude you have not really answer the question of why in my second scenario the code output behaved the way it is. But it's really ok if you don't know.

0 is no less indeterminate than 1954051118 or 3635659924944006912. You only think so because it doesn't "look random".

In the first case the second, third, and fourth element are the same every time. Would you say that they too are "determined and defined", and only the first element isn't?

@molbdnilo You're not wrong, but at the same time 0 is a more likely to be a candidate for default initialisation of some value, as opposed to 1954051118 or 3635659924944006912, wouldn't you agree? When was the last time you initialise your values to 1954051118?

In the first case the second, third, and fourth element might be the same every time, but the point is that they don't look intentional, do they? In the second scenario, where every element is consistently 0 every time, which made me think of the possibility of default initialisation to 0 by the compiler, even though that might not be necessarily the case.

@user3613025 People have actually measured, and zero is the most likely specific value to be found in an arbitrary memory location, so it is also the least surprising "indeterminate value". I think you're seeing patterns and intents where there aren't any. It's a very common thing to do (see for instance the current "AI" hype) but it is superstition, not science.

You should realize that the variables are uninitialized, and any/all usage of those variables other than setting them to a value results in undefined behavior, period, full stop. --  In the second scenario, where every element is consistently 0 every time, which made me think of the possibility of default initialisation to 0 by the compiler -- Any value van be "good" -- any value can be "bad".  This is why C++ is one of the most difficult languages to work with.  You cannot simply run bad code, and conclude "this is how C++ works".  Doing so will just lead to erroneous conclusions.

If you want to see undefined behavior in action, look at this example, and then take a look at this.  What is the difference?  The only difference is that there is a blank line before the return statement.  Why did putting a blank line in the source code make a difference in the output?

See How undefined is undefined behavior? When you have UB, nothing your program does can be trusted. In one case it might produce seemingly random values, in the next all zeros, or all ones, or something completely different. And it might even set fire to your computer or summon nasal demons. Well, perhaps not the last two things, but what ever result you get just is irrelevant.

@molbdnilo That's fair enough and a good point, ty

@PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the example, I can now see that the problem isn't particularly specific to adding another line of string initialisation like in my case, but rather could be caused by something as simple as adding another blank line.

I was looking for a slightly more elaborated answer than "it's just UB bro" and I appreciate that we got there in the end with our discussion, so thank you to the all of you.
